# Animation not working on input type button, but working on button tag

Tags: html, input, css-animations

As I am trying for animation on input type button it is not working, but animation is working for  tag and  tag

Comment: Add Your HTML & CSS Code Here

Comment: https://codepen.io/panyamsrinath/pen/vwaJYv

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Answer (score 0):

the correct selector should be `input[type="button"]`

Comment: above link is my code for the first two animation is working but not the last one any answer